# Как получить исполняющий текущую программу процессор?

Tags: wmi, runtime, процессор

Задача, собственно говоря, проста: нужно всего лишь получить текущий исполняющий процессор.

Искал решение, смотрел в сторону WinAPI функции `GetCurrentProcessorNumber`, но не понятно, как его преобразовать в экземпляр `Win32_Processor` класса (на моей однопроцессорной машине результат этой функции равен `2` — скорее всего, под словом "processor" в документации подразумевались "процессоры вообще", т.е. и видеокарты); а в самом классе `Win32_Processor` нет необходимых мне методов — под методы класса `Win32_Processor` даже отдельной вкладки с методами не завезли.

<sub>Код вызова функции `GetCurrentProcessorNumber` (на C)</sub>

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d", GetCurrentProcessorNumber());
}
```

Comment: А что, если - для эксперимента - попробовать с помощью CPUID получать номер APIC ID? Тоже на Вашей машине будет один и тот же? или приведите Ваш код, я у себя запущу

Comment: @S.H. дело в том, что CPUID мне не нравиться из-за того, что я не знаю его точного формата. у меня CPUID равен "CPU0", но на другой машине это может быть совсем по-другому.

Comment: К сожалению, я не смогу ничего подсказать. Могу предположить только, что видеокарты все таки не должны перечисляться этой функцией. Если Вы дополните вопрос, добавив туда код - я могу попробовать его запустить на разных машинах с разным числом процессоров. Но подсказать насет этой функции - не смогу без экспериментов. Может, еще знатоки подтянутся?

Comment: @S.H. код был прост: на C. `printf("%d", GetCurrentProcessorNumber())`. выводило `2`.