# Почему C считает, что у меня Windows Server 2003?

Tags: c, windows, windows-10, mingw, windows-server-2003

Пока я смотрел решение к моему [вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1247780), я случайно обнаружил вот эту вводящую в ступор строчку кода:

```c
#define WINVER 0x0502
```

У меня Windows 10, но это код от Windows Server 2003 ([документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt))…

Компилятор MinGW-W64. Windows 10 поставлялся вместе с купленной машиной, т.е. лицензия.

Объявил сам макрос `WINVER` заголовок `winresrc.h`. Значение `_WIN32_WINNT` такое же, как и у `WINVER`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ничего си не считает. Этот define показывает минимальную версию ОС, на которой скомпилированная программа сможет запуститься. А другие функции могут проверять и подключать различные реализации. К примеру, в visual studio c++ std::mutex по разному реализован для разных ос. Также WindowsSDK активно использует ее, что бы выбирать код, который точно будет работать на заданном множестве операционных систем.

Можете увеличить его до желаемого. Ничего страшного не случиться. Если не угадаете, программа может просто не запускаться (например, может начать ругаться при запуске, что такая то функция не найдена в такой то dll).

Comment: Тогда есть ли какой-нибудь способ определить версию текущую, а не минимальную Windows?

Comment: да, и она называется [GetVersion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getversion)

Comment: жаль, что нет макросов для этого. нормальной ли считается практика замены вручную значений некоторых макросов, как `#define WINVER 0x0a00` вместо `0x0502`?

Comment: Дело в том, что макросы - это штука времени компиляции, а данная функция - времени исполнения. Если Вы перенесете свою программу на другую машину, то define не поменяется - он уже "вшит" в Вашу программу. А GetVersion обращается в момент **выполнения** программы к ОС и узнает у нее.  Вы можете поменять значение, последствия я описал в ответе.

Comment: ах, да. при запуске на разных машинах версия может быть меньше, чем Windows 10. в 22:47 котелок уже не варит